# How to re-render a list of an array after an item is deleted? It give an error and doesn't re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am fetching a list of user from an API and I am trying to delete a user using "DELETE" method it gets delete but after the item is deleted it doesn't re-renders the list of the users, it give an error where I used map to map all the user in a table. The "DELETE" method is working properly it gives a 200 response but the maps doesn't work after that picks up the delete message.

Played around with the code tried different things which came to my mind but no luck.

Fetching users list :

```
export const getUsers = () =>{
  let url ='https://api.net/api/users';
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(initiateUserRequest(true));
    api({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET'
      })
        .then(response=>{
          dispatch(receiveUsers(response.data.data), false)
        })
        .catch(err=>{
          dispatch(errorUsers("Something went wrong:"+ err.message))
        })
    }
};
```

Deleting the user :

```
export const deleteUser = (username) =>{
  let url = `https://deletingusers/api/users/${username}`;

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(initiateUserRequest(true));

    api({
      url: url,
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
      .then(response=>{
        dispatch(receiveUsers(response),false)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        dispatch(errorUsers("Something went wrong:"+ err.message))
      })
  }
};
```

Table where data is mapped tabledata.map :

```
<TableBody>
            {tableData.map((prop, key) => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={key}>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                    {prop.username}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                    {prop.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                    {prop.email}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                    {prop.phoneNumber}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                    {prop.zip}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                    {prop.address}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                    {prop.status}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>
                    {prop.mobile}
                  </TableCell>
                  <Tooltip
                    id="tooltip-top"
                    title="Edit Task"
                    placement="top"
                    classes={{ tooltip: classes.tooltip }}
                  >
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="Edit"
                      className={classes.tableActionButton}
                    >
                      <Edit
                        onClick={() => this.props.onEditUser(prop)}
                        className={
                          classes.tableActionButtonIcon + " " + classes.edit
                        }
                      />

                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                  <Tooltip
                    id="tooltip-top-start"
                    title="Delete"
                    placement="top"
                    classes={{ tooltip: classes.tooltip }}
                  >
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="Close"
                      className={classes.tableActionButton}
                    >
                      <Close
                        className={
                          classes.tableActionButtonIcon + " " + classes.close
                        }
                        onClick={() => this.props.onDeleteUser(prop.username)}
                      />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
```

Can add more code if needed.

Comment: What does the error say? Also, what does the response for the DELETE contain? deletes often return an empty body

Comment: "TypeError: tableData.map is not a function" Yes an empty body is returned.

Comment: After making the `DELETE` request, you are dispatching `receiveUsers()` with the response, which is most likely empty. `dispatch(receiveUsers(response),false)`

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more ? And tell me how can it be resolved answer the question maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducer and Action were missing for deleting an item, I was trying to delete it directly which was causing an error of not deleting it from the store. So I added an action and reducer for delete and included my DELETE method properly. I was deleting it using a username of the user which I selected. So I sent the selected user to my reducer through which the user was also deleted from the store and the api as well.

Reducer :

```
 case types.DELETE_USER:
      newState = {
        usersData: {},
        isFetching: true,
        error: false
      };
      return{
        ...state, usersDetail: newState.usersData.filter( item => item.username !==action.username)
      };
```

Action :

```
const deleteUsers =(username, isFetching) =>{
  return{
    type: types.DELETE_USER,
    username,
    isFetching
  }
};

export const deleteUser = (username) =>{
  let url = `www.api.com ${username}`;

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(initiateUserRequest(true));

    api({
      url: url,
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
      .then(response=>{
        dispatch(deleteUsers(response),true)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        dispatch(errorUsers("Something went wrong:"+ err.message))
      })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the deleted username from the original users array in the deleteUser function by sending the tableData as an argument to the deleteUser.

```
export const deleteUser = (username,tableData) =>{ // send tableData overhere
```

let url = `https://deletingusers/api/users/${username}`;

return dispatch => {
    dispatch(initiateUserRequest(true));

```
api({
  url: url,
  method: 'DELETE',
})
  .then(response=>{
    const updatedTableData = tableData.filter(data => data.username !== username)
    dispatch(receiveUsers(updatedTableData),false)
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    dispatch(errorUsers("Something went wrong:"+ err.message))
  })
```

}
};